# Make div follow cursor on scroll additionally to mousemove

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to implement some custom cursor - a div that moves with the cursor. To do so, I use the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);

handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    const y = event.pageY;
    const x = event.pageX;

    const ref = document.querySelector('.follow-cursor');
    ref.style.left = x + 'px';
    ref.style.top = y + 'px';
};
```

It works fine, but there's one more problem: scrolling. So far, the **div is not moving on scroll and hence not following the cursor on scroll**. How can I change that? Reference: [this website](https://www.explose.lu/).

Comment: can you please provide a working example?

Comment: @SametC the link is a working example, but having a look at the non-functional code OP has would be good

Comment: yes its an example for what he will do, but yes the non-functional code would be great. You are right.

Comment: @SametC That's all I have so far, I didn't figure a way yet to include scrolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is how the site you linked to does this, but it works.

```
handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    const y = event.pageY;
    const x = event.pageX;
    const ref = document.querySelector('.follow-cursor')
    const scrollLeft = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
    const scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    ref.style.left =  x - scrollLeft + 'px';
    ref.style.top = y - scrollTop + 'px';
};
```

If you apply style `position: fixed` to your .follow-cursor it should work.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/bf5wy9v3/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah NickSlash's answer works fine.
You can try both.
Just in this case do not forget to add the id in the html

```
const cursor = document.getElementById("cursor")
const moveCursor = (event) => {
  const y = event.pageY
  const x = event.pageX
  const scrollLeft =
window.pageXOffset !== undefined
  ? window.pageXOffset
  : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body)
      .scrollLeft
onst scrollTop =
window.pageYOffset !== undefined
  ? window.pageYOffset
  : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body)
      .scrollTop
cursor.style.left = x - scrollLeft + "px"
cursor.style.top = y - scrollTop + "px"`}`
document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCursor)
```